# How can I make go get work with a repo on a local server

Tags: go, github

I've got a git repo on a local server.  I can clone from it with `git clone user@10.xxx.yyy.zzz:/srv/git/liqid.git` where the user has ssh access and read/write to the git/ directory.

When I try to use it with `go get -v user@10.xxx.yyy.zzz:/srv/git/liqid.git` it gives

`go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode`

I've tried various other combinations like leaving out the `:`, but they all fail.

Can `go get` work with a repo on a local server?

Comment: It looks like go is looking for a version instead of an IP. Use your hosts file and set a hostname to whatever your repo ip is and try that.

Comment: See [Remote import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

Comment: When I use the name that is in /etc/hosts I get `unrecognized import path "controller/srv/git/liqid.git/liqid.controller.service": import path does not begin with hostname`

Comment: @Peter - that is for import statements not `go get ...`

Comment: You must provide git the appropriate credentials which **cannot** be done in `go get` (really). Git has several options to use credentials choose any one but you must use go get without ports, credentials, etc.

Comment: I have ssh access to the private server via rsa keys just like with bitbucket or gitub.  None of the error messages mention authentication issues.

Comment: @DeanSchulze it's not that it's an authentication issue; it's that you're trying to pass git details to `go get`, which you cannot. `go get` takes a *package*, not a git URL. If you want it to work with `go get`, you'll need to configure `git` to be able to access that repo without passing those details explicitly, as Volker said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I've learned about using `go get` for packages and modules when the git repo is on a private server.  I hope it helps someone else to have all the steps documented in one place.

**Using Packages And Modules With git Repositories on Private Servers**

Here are all the steps needed to use Go packages and modules with git repositories on private servers.  These are servers with IP addresses such as 10.xxx.yyy.zzz or 192.168.xxx.yyy.  No github or gitlab is assumed to exist on these servers so there is no web server running on port 80, which is the assumption that `go get` is based on.  Your private server only needs to have `sshd` running.

Install the latest version of Go and be sure the GOPATH is set.  The first element in your GOPATH is where the code from these examples will be downloaded to.

You'll need another computer on your network where you will create git repositories.  This will be your private git server.

If you want to skip all of the setup steps and example code you can check the two Key Differences sections that list the differences when using packages or modules with a private server instead of a public git repository.

**The source code**

Put `dateutil.go` and `stringutil.go` in the directory structures shown below for both packages and modules.

dateutil.go:

```
package datepackage

import "time"

func GetTime() time.Time {
    return time.Now().Local()
}
```

stringutil.go:

```
package stringpackage

import "strings"

func ToUpperCase(s string) string {

    return strings.ToUpper(s)
}
```

main.go (put main.go somewhere outside of the directory structure shown below):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-dateutil/datepackage"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("github:  " + stringpackage.ToUpperCase("test"))
    fmt.Println("github:  " + datepackage.GetTime().String())
}
```

These files can be found on github.com

```
git@github.com:dwschulze/go-package-test-dateutil.git

git@github.com:dwschulze/go-package-test-stringutil.git

git@github.com:dwschulze/go-module-package-test-drivers.git
```

**Create Packages Using the GOPATH Convention**

Create a directory structure like this outside of your GOPATH and add the files above.  This follows the GOPATH convention, but you don't need these files in you GOPATH.

```
package
├── github
│   ├── dateutil
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── datepackage
│   │           └── dateutil.go
│   └── stringutil
│       └── src
│           └── stringpackage
│               └── stringutil.go
└── your-local-git-repo-hostname
    ├── dateutil
    │   └── src
    │       └── datepackage
    │           └── dateutil.go
    └── stringutil
        └── src
            └── stringpackage
                └── stringutil.go
```

`your-local-git-repo-hostname` is the hostname or IP address of your private git server where you'll create git repos (not the machine where you currently have this code).  There is an undocumented requirement that the hostname for the `go get` command have a `.` in it.  If the hostname of your private git server doesn't have a `.` in it then use its IP address.  Add ssh key access to your private git server with `ssh-copy-id`.

**Using a Private repo on github**

We'll start with the simplest case, using packages from github.com.  You'll need a github account with ssh key access setup.

Create git repos in the two `src/` directories under `github/` that you created above using `git init`

```
package
├── github
│   ├── dateutil
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── ...
│   └── stringutil
│       └── src
|           └── ...
```

Add and commit the `datepackage/` and `stringpackage/` dirs respectively to your git repos.

Create two private github repos named `go-package-test-dateutil` and `go-package-test-stringutil` in your account on github.com.  Follow the instructions to set the remotes in your local git repos in your `src/` directories to their respective github repositories.  Push the code.

Since your repos are private you'll have to use ssh public key access to download the code.  Since `go get` uses https by default you'll need to add this to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Run these commands to put the code you just pushed to github.com into your `GOPATH`:

```
go get github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage/

go get github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-dateutil/datepackage/
```

The packages get downloaded into the `pkg/` and `src/` directories of the first element in your GOPATH.

In the directory with the `main.go` file you created above type `go run main.go` and the results will be printed to the console.

**Create Git Repositories on Your Private Server**

Now you'll create git repos on your private git server.  To keep this simple you'll just use `git init --bare`.  There's no need to install github or gitlab.  On your private git server you'll need to have `sshd` running and have ssh key access from the machine where your code is.  The new repos will be in `/home/myusername/gitrepo`.

```
git init /home/myusername/gitrepo/go-package-test-dateutil --bare

git init /home/myusername/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil --bare
```

The `go get` command has an undocumented requirement that the hostname have a `.` in it.  If the hostname of your private git server doesn't have a `.` in it then use its IP address, which is what I'll do throughout the rest of this example.  Assume the machine's IP address is 192.168.0.12

Copy the `dateutil.go` and `stringutil.go` files that you created earlier into the directories under `your-local-git-repo-hostname`:

```
package
├── github
|   ...
└── your-local-git-repo-hostname
    ├── dateutil
    │   └── src
    │       └── datepackage
    │           └── dateutil.go
    └── stringutil
        └── src
            └── stringpackage
                └── stringutil.go
```

In the two `src/` directories create local git repos as you did before and add and commit the code.  Set the remotes to the git repo that you created on your private git server

```
git remote add origin myusername@your-local-git-repo-hostname:gitrepo/go-package-test-dateutil


git remote add origin myusername@your-local-git-repo-hostname:gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil
```

You'll need another entry in `~/.gitconfig` for your private git server:

```
git config --global url."myusername@your-local-git-repo-hostname:".insteadOf "https://192.168.0.12/"
```

Now push the code.  Note that this code is not yet in your GOPATH.

Use `go get` to retrieve the code from your private git server.  It's necessary to add a ".git" suffix to the directory name where you created the git repos with `git init --bare` on your private git server.  That tells `go get` that this is a git repository rather than some other version control system.

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil.git/stringpackage


go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-dateutil.git/datepackage
```

The packages get downloaded into the pkg/ and src/ directories of the first element in your `GOPATH`.

```
└── src
    ├── 192.168.0.12
    │   └── gitrepo
    │       ├── go-module-test-dateutil.git
    │       │   ├── dateutil.go
    │       │   └── go.mod
    │       ├── go-package-test-dateutil.git
    │       │   └── datepackage
    │       │       └── dateutil.go
    │       └── go-package-test-stringutil.git
    │           └── stringpackage
    │               └── stringutil.go
```

In your `main.go` code add two import statements to the packages on your private git server

```
package main

import (
    dpkg "192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-dateutil.git/datepackage"
    strpkg "192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil.git/stringpackage"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-dateutil/datepackage"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("github:  " + stringpackage.ToUpperCase("test"))
    fmt.Println("github:  " + datepackage.GetTime().String())
    fmt.Println("local:  " + strpkg.ToUpperCase("test"))
    fmt.Println("local:  " + dpkg.GetTime().String())
}
```

Note the use of the aliases `dpkg` and `strpkg` in the two new `import` statements because the `import` statements have duplicate package names (the last element in the import statement).

Now you can run the code with `go run main.go`.

Key differences between using a private repo on guthub.com and a repo on a private git server:

- Modifying ~/.gitconfig
- Adding the .git suffix in go get statements
- The hostname in `go get` and  `import` statements must have a dot in it

**Creating Modules Using Private Repositories**

Create a directory structure like this parallel to the `packages/` directory you created above.  Copy the `dateutil.go` and `stringutil.go` files from above.  Change the package statements to `datemod` and `stringmod` respectively.  You'll create the `go.mod` files later.

```
module
├── github
│   ├── datemodule
│   │   ├── dateutil.go
│   │   └── go.mod
│   └── stringmodule
│       ├── go.mod
│       └── stringutil.go
└── 192.168.0.12
    ├── datemodule
    │   ├── dateutil.go
    │   └── go.mod
    └── stringmodule
        ├── go.mod
        └── stringutil.go
```

Note that the directory names are different from the package names.  Packages don't have to follow directory names.

Generate the `go.mod` files by executing the following commands in these directories:

In `github/datemodule/`

```
go mod init github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod
```

In `github/stringmodule/`

```
go mod init github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-stringutilmod
```

In `192.168.0.12/datemodule/`

```
go mod init 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git
```

In `192.168.0.12/stringmodule/`

```
go mod init 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git
```

In the four `datemodule/` and `stringmodule/` directories above create a git repo with `git init` and add and commit the files.

Create two private repos on github.com named `go-module-test-dateutilmod` and `go-module-test-stringutilmod`.  Follow the instructions to set the remotes in your respective local git repos under the `github/` directory.  Push the code.

On your private git server create two git repos with

```
git init /home/myusername/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil --bare

git init /home/myusername/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil --bare
```

Set the remotes in the respective git repos under `192.168.0.12/` directory with

```
git remote add origin myusername@192.168.0.12:gitrepo/go-package-test-dateutil


git remote add origin myusername@192.168.0.12:gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil
```

Push the code.

Now you have four different modules, two each in repositories in your github.com account and your private git server.

In another directory create a `main.go` program to use these modules:

```
package main

import (
    datemodlocal "192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git"
    stringmodlocal "192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod"
    "github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-stringutilmod"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("github:  " + stringmod.ToUpperCase("test"))
    fmt.Println("github:  " + datemod.GetTime().String())
    fmt.Println("local:  " + stringmodlocal.ToUpperCase("test"))
    fmt.Println("local:  " + datemodlocal.GetTime().String())
    fmt.Println("local toString:  " + datemodlocal.GetTimeStr())
}
```

To use modules with private repos we have to set `GOPRIVATE`

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=192.168.0.12/gitrepo/*,github.com/your-github-username/*
```

When `GOPRIVATE` is set modules will be pulled directly from the specified git repos instead of the [Go public proxy](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules).

Now run

```
$ go mod init module-driver
  go: creating new go.mod: module module-driver
$ cat go.mod
  module module-driver

  go 1.15
```

Now execute `main.go`.  It will download the modules from github.com and your private git server before running the code:

```
$ go run main.go
go: finding module for package github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-dateutilmod
go: finding module for package github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-stringutilmod
go: finding module for package 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git
go: finding module for package 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git
go: downloading 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git v0.0.1
go: downloading 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git v0.0.3
go: downloading github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-dateutilmod v0.0.1
go: downloading github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-stringutilmod v0.0.1
go: found 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git in 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git v0.0.3
go: found 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git in 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git v0.0.1
go: found github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-dateutilmod in github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-dateutilmod v0.0.1
go: found github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-stringutilmod in github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-stringutilmod v0.0.1
github:  TEST
github:  2020-12-08 07:57:02.969147007 -0700 MST
local:  TEST
local:  2020-12-08 07:57:02.969220121 -0700 MST
local toString:  2020-12-08 07:57:02.969222359 -0700 MST  (dev2 branch)
local GetTimeStr3:  2020-12-08 07:57:02.96925053 -0700 MST  (dev2 branch)
```

You didn't have to run `go get` to download these modules before running the code.  The `go.mod` was also modified

```
$ cat go.mod
module module-driver

go 1.15

require (
    192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git v0.0.3 // indirect
    192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git v0.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-dateutilmod v0.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/dwschulze/go-module-test-stringutilmod v0.0.1 // indirect
)
```

You can download your modules with go get to test that your environment is set up correctly:

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-stringutil.git
go get github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod
go get github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-stringutilmod
```

Again note the use of the `.git` suffix on the repository path for your private git server.  Without this `go get` will use https instead of git (which would use ssh).

Running `go get` modifies the `go.mod` file.  While some people say you can manually modify the `go.mod` file others say that you should not edit `go.mod` manually and instead use `go get` to make any modifications.

Downloading the module code either with `go get` or `go run main.go` downloads the code into `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`.  Since no version was specified it will pull the latest [semantic version tag](https://blog.golang.org/versioning-proposal) for that module.

Semantic versioning is done with tags which are just a commit.  Tags are independent of branches so if the latest `semver` was done on a branch other than master it will pull that version.

To specify a specific version use

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git@v0.0.1
```

This will update the entry in `go.mod` if one already exists

You should be able to delete `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/` directory and do `go run main.go` again.  You'll see Go downloading the needed modules before running the code.

Key Differences When Using Modules From a Private Repository

- Modifying ~/.gitconfig
- Adding the .git suffix for the repos on your private server
- The hostname of your private server must have a dot in it, or use its IP address
- Set `GOPRIVATE` with `go env -w GOPRIVATE=...`

**Using code on a different branch**

Semantic version tags are independent of branches, but there is one case where `go get` can use a branch.  If you want to `go get` the latest commit from a branch you can append `@branchname` like this:

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-module-test-dateutil.git@branchname
```

If the latest commit on the branch does not have a `semver` tag `go get` will create a pseudo-version using the next `semver` tag number and a timestammp and hash.

**FAQs**

What does a `410 Gone` error mean when downloading a module?

```
go get github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod
go: downloading github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod v0.0.1
go get github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod: github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod@v0.0.1: verifying module: github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod@v0.0.1: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod@v0.0.1: 410 Gone
    server response: not found: github.com/your-github-username/go-module-test-dateutilmod@v0.0.1: invalid version: unknown revision v0.0.1
```

This can happen if you don't have GOPRIVATE set.  Go tries to retrieve your (private) modules from the Go public proxy, but it can't find them there.

**Resources**

[Using private repos from public git hosting services.  A demonstration of how GOPRIVATE and GOPROXY work.](https://play-with-go.dev/working-with-private-modules_go115_en/)