# go get can't work with a non-routeable IP address

Tags: git, go, go-get

I have a git repo setup on a computer on my local network (192.168.0.12).  It has an entry in `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.0.12    ubuntu-18-extssd
```

go get doesn't recognize my hostname (`ubuntu-18-extssd`) as a host name so I use the IP address instead.

Now when I try with go get like this

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage
```

it returns the error

```
package 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage: unrecognized import path "192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage": https fetch: Get "https://192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage?go-get=1": dial tcp 192.168.0.12:443: connect: connection refused
```

So I tell git to use ssh instead:

```
git config --global url."dean@192.168.0.12:".insteadOf "https://192.168.0.12/"
```

and in my ~/.gitconfig I have

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "dean@192.168.0.12:"]
    insteadOf = https://192.168.0.12/
```

But go get still gives the same error.  The entry for github works, though.

Why is the combination of `go get` and `git` still trying to use https when I've told it to use ssh instead?

Comment: Host names are part of the import path, not the package name.  I've also tried with the hostname and it fails with the same message.  Here is the git origin:

`$ git remote --v
origin dean@ubuntu-18-extssd:gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil (fetch)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant import path. The mechanism for locating repositories Is documented at https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Comment: Those are all public URLs.  The problem I've run into is that `go get` doesn't know what to do with a git repo on a private, on-prem, non-routable IP.  `go get` has a proxy setup that does some magic with those well-known public IPs.  Apparently it fails with a non-routable IP.

Comment: Is port 443 open on 192.168.0.12? Sounds like port 22 or 21 (SSH) is open but not 443.  Do you have a web server running on 192.168.0.12?  The IP address 192.168.0.12 is most definitely routable, just not routable across the internet. What happens if you open a browser and go to `https://192.168.0.12`?  The error states that the connection has been refused.

Comment: No web server running on my host.  I use ssh for git access.  The .gitconfig entry should be converting the https: request to ssh.  I've also tried ssh://dean@192.168.0.12: but get the same result.

Comment: Here's my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645866/how-can-i-make-go-get-work-with-a-repo-on-a-local-server/65209006#65209006). It covers, packages, modules, and `go get`.

Comment: Here's my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645866/how-can-i-make-go-get-work-with-a-repo-on-a-local-server/65209006#65209006) covering packages, modules, and `go get`.

Comment: Here's my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645866/how-can-i-make-go-get-work-with-a-repo-on-a-local-server/65209006#65209006) covering packages, modules, and `go get`.

Answer (score 1):

Go cannot infer the repository type from `192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage` directly, so it's trying to lookup the meta tags at `https://192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage?go-get=1`:

> If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import over https/http and looks for a  tag in the document's HTML .

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

If you don't want to run a server that returns the appropriate meta tags you have to let Go know that the package is in a git repository by adding `.git` to the import path. Use one of the following commands, depending on where your repository is located:

```
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage.git
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo/go-package-test-stringutil.git/stringpackage
go get 192.168.0.12/gitrepo.git/go-package-test-stringutil/stringpackage
```