# How can you specify which ssh key `go get` will use

Tags: git, go, github, ssh-keys, go-get

I'm using two different github accounts (personal and work) on the same laptop (running Ubuntu version 20). I need to be able to access private repos from work using the ssh key for my work github account.

I've made it all work using some neat git config controls, i.e. in my `~/.gitconfig` file I've put:

```
[url "git@github.com:work_account/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/work_account/
[includeIf "gitdir:~/src/github.com/personal_account/"]
    path=~/.gitconfig_personal
[includeIf "gitdir:~/src/github.com/work_account/"]
    path=~/.gitconfig_work
```

The personal config contains:

```
[user]
name = Your Name
email = your.name@gmail.com
[core]
sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The work config contains:

```
[user]
name = Your Name
email = your.name@work.com
signingkey = <ID of GPG key>
[core]
sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
[commit]
gpgsign = true
[gpg]
program = gpg
```

This all works great for pulling and pushing from github (and signing work commits with a gpg key), but it is failing for `go get` on private repos. For some bizarre reason `go get` is trying to use my personal ssh key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) instead of my work ssh key (`~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`). I've set the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable, i.e.

```
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/work_account/*
```

The output of go get is like:

```
$ go get github.com/work_account/private_repo
go get github.com/work_account/private_repo: module github.com/work_account/private_repo: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/marc/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ff3efb332cb48232e5da90ff2073685cbdac4a86e3a47aa11663696f4943637a: exit status 128:
        ERROR: Repository not found.
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I can see that my ssh agent has both keys:

```
$ ssh-add -l
521 SHA256:EKvhgg24_blah_bApjLSqX4J7l0 your.name@work.com (ECDSA)
4096 SHA256:r/qcO94F+ox_blah_JkTiVk+aERk your.name@gmail.com (RSA)
```

When I remove my personal ssh key (i.e. `rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa*`) then `go get` works just fine on the private repo, so I know it is definitely just trying to use the wrong ssh key. For some reason it is ignoring the git config `core.sshCommand`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and digging around, I've found a solution. If I set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa"` in the private repo then `go get` uses the correct ssh key and then works for private repos. It seems that `go get` ignores the git config `core.sshCommand` but is taking into account the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`.

To simplify my life I've used the program `direnv` to set this environment variable in the folder I keep my work repos in. The `.envrc` file in the top level folder looks like this:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your `~/.ssh/config` file. If it doesn't exist, just create it. It specifies the ssh key to use for each host. You can add sort of aliases by adding invalid domains:

```
Host gitlab.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host github.invalid
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And then every time you use git@github.invalid, you use the correct ssh key.

Related is this addition to `~/.gitconfig`, which helps with importing private repositories. It uses ssh got all git operations with these hosts:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

Also see environmental variable `GOPRIVATE` which lists private repositories not to use proxy with. [Example](https://goproxy.io/docs/GOPRIVATE-env.html):

```
GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,rsc.io/private
```

Comment: This is all useful stuff, but it doesn't really solve the problem of trying to get `go get` to work with two different github accounts, each with their own ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SSH-Agent. `ssh-agent` is part of the openssh. It also holds your keys and certificates unencrypted in memory. They are ready for use by ssh.

For example it is very helpful when you have ssh-key with a `passphase`. By default it will ask you to enter the key passphase every time, go is trying to clone/pull code from a upstream.

There are few commands, you can use:

- `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` - See if agent is assigned to the current session. the `SSH_AGENT_PID` variable should return pid of the `ssh-agent`.
- `eval $(ssh-agent)` - start a new `ssh-agent` session.
- `ssh-add -l` - List keys available in your ssh session
- `ssh-add ~/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa` - Add the `~/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa` key to current session.

Example session can be:

```
ip-192-168-200-63:tf-r0 daniel$ echo $SSH_AGENT_SOCK
ip-192-168-200-63:tf-r0 daniel ^C

ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 50734
ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID 
50734
ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/daniel/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/daniel/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa (/Users/daniel/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa)
ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:nm/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /Users/daniel/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa (RSA)
ip-192-168-200-63:src daniel$
```

After that I can pull remote code with ssh key protected by passphase without entering it every time, key is required.

Comment: I am already using `ssh-agent` and it can see both ssh keys.

Comment: Do you still see the error? There is really good expain about go get and go modules written by @DeanSchulze : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645866/how-can-i-make-go-get-work-with-a-repo-on-a-local-server/65209006#65209006

Comment: Yeah, that is an interesting article. I did find the answer (see the accepted answer). Essentially it was pulling the wrong key from the `ssh-agent` as it was ignoring the git config `core.sshCommand`. But, setting the environment variable, instead of the config setting, works, for some bizarre reason! i.e. ```export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa"```