# Fetch 'go get' project from local bare git repo

Tags: git, go

I'm trying to simulate remote repository for Go dependency as local git repo. I'm aware of `go mod edit -replace` etc., but for my use case I need Go command to fetch dependency from git repo locally.

To simulate it with minimal reproducible example, I created bare git repo:

```bash
# in /tmp/git/repo1
git init --bare
```

Then cloned the repo, created go project, and pushed it back:

```bash
# in /tmp/projects/
git clone file:///tmp/git/repo1
cd repo1
go mod init git.localhost/repo1
git add go.mod && git commit -m "init: go mod init localhost" && git push origin
```

Just in case, checked bare repo updated successfully:

```bash
# in /tmp/git/repo1
git cat-file -p $(cat refs/heads/master) | grep init
# init: go mod init localhost
```

Then I created "client" go project, updated git config and tried to fetch it using `go get`:

```bash
# in /tmp/go-proj
go mod init example.com
git config --global url."file:///tmp/git/".insteadOf "https://git.localhost/"
go get git.localhost/repo1
```

But got this error:

```
go: unrecognized import path "git.localhost/repo1": https fetch: Get "https://git.localhost/repo1?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup git.localhost on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

Also, I tried to update `GOPRIVATE` env and set git config allow=always for `file` protocol:

```bash
export GOPRIVATE="git.localhost/*"
git config --global protocol.file.allow always
```

And checked git can clone this repo by using:

```bash
git clone https://git.localhost/repo1
# successfully cloned from bare repo
```

Is it possible to get dependency from local git bare repo using `go get`?

---

Update:
Added `GOPROXY` env, so now my `go env` has:

```
GOPRIVATE="git.localhost/*"
GOPROXY="direct"
```

and `git config --global` has:

```
url.file:///tmp/git/.insteadof=https://git.localhost/
protocol.file.allow=always
```

Update2:

Verbose output for `go get` command:

```bash
GOFLAGS="-v -x" go get git.localhost/repo1
# get https://git.localhost/?go-get=1
# get https://git.localhost/repo1?go-get=1
# get https://git.localhost/?go-get=1: Get "https://git.localhost/?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup git.localhost on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
# get https://git.localhost/repo1?go-get=1: Get "https://git.localhost/repo1?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup git.localhost on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
go: unrecognized import path "git.localhost/repo1": https fetch: Get "https://git.localhost/repo1?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup git.localhost on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I started primitive HTTP web server to return HTML page for `go get` requests with `<meta>` go-import tag. It specifies the location of git repository as `https://git.localhost/<repo-name>` and then `go get` uses git to fetch this repo and `insteadOf` git config replaces `https://git.localhost` with `file:///` location. Also, `GOINSECURE="git.localhost/*` environment is required to request go-get requests using http.

This is my server handler (with submodule and semver support):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

// repo names: /repo /repo/module /repo/ /repo/submodule /repo/v2
var reRepo = regexp.MustCompile(`^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?(?:.+)?$`)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        repoParts := reRepo.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
        if len(repoParts) == 0 {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        name := repoParts[1]
        log.Printf("Resolve %s => %s", r.URL.Path, name)

        var sb strings.Builder
        sb.WriteString("<html><head>")
        sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(`<meta name="go-import" content="git.localhost/%s git https://git.localhost/%s" />`, name, name))
        sb.WriteString("</head></html>")
        fmt.Fprint(w, sb.String())
    }))
}
```

Comment: Well done, more detailed than my answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is the issue, test your `go get` command with first:

```
export GOPROXY=direct
```

That should allow `go get` to fetch the dependency from the local Git repository without any issues.
That should be set *in addition* to your other settings, like your `export GOPRIVATE="git.localhost/*"` and your Git `insteadOf` directive.

---

The OP adds in the comments:

> Looks like go get is trying to fetch some meta data via http from dependency host (git.localhost in my case), then create package git repo in `go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/{hash}` and then fetch dependency code using git, where git applies `isnteadOf` replace.
>
> So I'm going to try create simple http server to respond with meta information with VCS, Prefix and RepoRoot url response to http://git.localhost/?go-get=1 URL

This is indeed what is illustrated in "[How can I make go get work with a repo on a local server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60645866/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, I tried `GOPROXY` but has the same issue (updated question)

Comment: @Kirill Do you have any `HTTP(S)_PROXY` environment variable in place?

Comment: No, I don't have proxies, the only proxy env for `env | grep -i proxy` is `GOPROXY=direct`

Comment: @Kirill Is there any clue with a `GOFLAGS="-v" go get git.localhost/repo1`?

Comment: I tried with `-v -x` and it looks it `go get` command tried to connect via TCP to localhost (see log in updated question).

Comment: Looks like `go get` is trying to fetch some meta data via http from dependency host (`git.localhost` in my case), then create package git repo in `go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/{hash}` and then fetch dependency code using git, where git applies `isnteadOf` replace. So I'm going to try create simple http server to respond with meta information with `VCS`, `Prefix` and `RepoRoot` url response to `http://git.localhost/?go-get=1` URL.

Comment: @Kirill I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added a link to another answer which could illustrate what you want to do.